# Microsoft Access 2010: Update query - issue with "date/time" data type

Tags: ms-access

I am not able to find an answer online and pretty stumped by the following issue: I'm trying to us an update query to update date field from one table into another. Both fields have the same "date/time" data type. When I create an update query it returns blank values....copy of the SQL code below

```
UPDATE [MIDs with comments] INNER JOIN [account status for MIDs with comments table] 
       ON [MIDs with comments].[Merchant Number] = 
          [account status for MIDs with comments table].[Merchant Number] 
SET [MIDs with comments].[Account Open Date] = 
    [account status for MIDs with comments table].[ACCT_OPEN_DT];
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here as the query seems pretty simple. When I do regular select query it returns values without any problems..

Please help.

Comment: Formatted is not the same as data type. What is the data type in each table? Are you working from tables or queries?

Comment: I'm working with 2 tables. Both fields have the same data type: Date/Time. I used "formated" word incorrectly here. Sorry

Comment: Are both tables Access (Jet) tables? I had cases where a date was valid in Access but not in SQL server (like 1/1/1011).

Comment: um..not sure what "jet" means :(. However both tables are located in the same access database. I guess I'm pretty green in MS Access so far. I am not using SQL server, I was refering to SQL View of a query.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'm not sure what "fixed" my issue, however the query worked after I used the Immediate window and code provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm puzzled about what you meant when you said your `UPDATE` query "*returns blank values*".  An `UPDATE` query does not return values, blank or otherwise.

If you're using Access' query designer to build your query, then switching to Datasheet View, that does not actually execute the query.  To execute it, click the Run icon (red exclamation point).

If that wasn't the explanation, I'll suggest you save your query then try this in the Immediate window (you can go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).

```vba
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Set db = CurrentDb()
db.Execute "Your query name here", dbFailOnError
? db.RecordsAffected
```

If the `.Execute` line throws an error, tell us the full text of the error message.

If no error, perhaps `RecordsAffected` will be zero.  In that case we will need to investigate further to determine why no records were updated.

Comment: Hi, I guess my explanation confused everyone :D

Comment: Hi, I guess my explanation confused everyone :D I clicked on "Create Query" and chose "Update". I dropped two tables and joined them. I need to update "Account Open Date" field with the date from another table called "ACCT_OPEN_DT". When I click on Datasheet view each row is blank and does not reflect values from "ACCT_OPEN_DT"......I tried to use immediate window and I did not get any errors just a number of records at the end...

Comment: So, in the Immediate window, your query ran without error and you got some number greater than zero for `RecordsAffected`.  Is that correct?  If so I don't understand where the problem is.